# calibrating colors in image file

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge, accord.net

I need to compare colors from images that may be filmed at different lightning environment.

I can ensure that the film will contain a well known colors (like "pure" red green and blue)

I want to write a code in c# that will remove all the environment lightning from the images using the known colors to enable good compression between them.

I'm not too familiar with image processing, I saw the AForge and the Accord.NET libraries but i didnt find a way to do it?

I'll be glad for any suggestion or any staring point

Thanks

Comment: _I can ensure that the film will contain a well known colors_ Do you also know where those colors are? Also: What differences will there be in the lighting? Only in brightness or also shades of color?

Comment: @TaW, it will contain a known rectangles with known colors. I prefer to find the rectangles automatically, but if it needed i'll ask the user to mark them. about the lightning, the pictures suppose to be film in well lightning room but it might be slightly different light, if it sun or white or yellow lamp, and different cameras etc.